# nginx replace last part of dynamic URL

Tags: nginx

I want requests coming for the URL

```
https://my-domain.com/api/data/app/public/customers/<id>/wrong/
```

redirecting to

```
https://my-domain.com/api/data/app/public/customers/<id>/correct/
```

where `<id>` is a number in the range 1 to 10000.

Everything else should just be passed. Should I use a regex rewrite rule for this or is there a simpler possibility?